# Can I use AWS IAM as a provider for Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I have a serverless web application and I would like to allow only certain AWS accounts to login and use the application.

Do you know if AWS Cognito is capable of providing authentication and authorization only to certain AWS accounts?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible to grant login for AWS IAM Users through Cognito. However, if you plan to use federated identity providers like Active Directory (Which supports SAML), you can grant access to both AWS Accounts and Cognito.